# Fibonacci sequence will not print anything but the number that is inputted by the user

Tags: java, fibonacci

Here is my main method, I am trying to call the Fibonacci sequence to tell me what number would be at the location the user inputs:

```
import java.util.Scanner; //import Scanner

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
         
       System.out.println("enter number");
       Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); 
       int n = input.nextInt();
         
       Fibonacci fibonacci_test = new Fibonacci();
       fibonacci_test.Recursivefibonacci(n);
         
    }
}
```

Here is my Fibonacci code that I have:

```
public class Fibonacci {
//Fn=F(n-1)+F(n-2)
    
        
    //The recursive Fibonacci method 
    public int Recursivefibonacci(int n) {
       
        if(n==0) {
            return 0;
        } if(n==1) {
            return 1;
        }else {
            
        int fib = Recursivefibonacci(n-1)+Recursivefibonacci(n-2);
        return fib;
        }
            
    }
}
```

I cannot get this thing to print anything. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because you're not printing anything else.
Your method doesn't print anything (just returns a value), and your main doesn't print anything (aside from "enter number").

You can try changing: `fibonacci_test.Recursivefibonacci(n);` to `println (fibonacci_test.Recursivefibonacci(n));`

Comment: Ive taken out the println, im not sure what im doing wrong with it. it wont allow me to print n after the return, and if it do it before it, it just keeps throwing out numbers when i just need 1 number. Maybe im over thinking this. but ive been trying to write this thing for 3 hours, watching videos and looking up tutorials and i just cant get it to do what i want it to do

Comment: You can't add println after return as return ends the method (it won't run anything after that). Adding println before returns seemingly random numbers because every time the method is called, it will output a number (this includes the recursion). However, this also means that the last number output should be the correct number that you want. Alternatively you can just print the last output with: println ( fibonacci_test.Recursivefibonacci(n));

Comment: @WesleyHarrison just to clarify eClySe, put the print in your main function so you can see just the final output.

Answer (score 1):

It would be more appropriate to return `Recursivefibonacci(n-1)+Recursivefibonacci(n-2);`rather than storing it in a variable.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question and while style is a good thing it's not generally helpful in this case. Maybe he is using a live debugger and saving it to a variable makes it easy to check the output

Answer (score 1):

I did this in python, you can have a look, try to adapt it to java, this might help you. Recursivity can be a headache but seems good.

```
def fib(n):
    if n == 0:
        return 0
    if n <= 1:
        return 1
    res = (fib(n-1)+ fib(n-2))
    return res
```

///////
Probably your code will look somehow like this:

```
public int Recursivefibonacci(int n) {
    if(n == 0){
       return 0;

}
if(n <= 1) {
   return 1;
    } 

    int fib = Recursivefibonacci(n-1)+Recursivefibonacci(n-2);
    return fib;
        
}
```

Try it! and let me know if it worked.